# Color branches of dendrogram using an existing column

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram, dendextend

I have a data frame which I am trying to cluster. I am using `hclust` right now. In my data frame, there is a `FLAG` column which I would like to color the dendrogram by. By the resulting picture, I am trying to figure out similarities among various `FLAG` categories. My data frame looks something like this:

```
FLAG    ColA    ColB    ColC    ColD
```

I am clustering on `colA`, `colB`, `colC` and `colD`. I would like to cluster these and color them according to `FLAG` categories. Ex - color red if 1, blue if 0 (I have only two categories). Right now I am using the vanilla version of cluster plotting.

```
hc<-hclust(dist(data[2:5]),method='complete')
plot(hc)
```

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to color the branches of a dendrogram based on a certain variable then the following code (largely taken from the help for the dendrapply function) should give the desired result:

```
x<-1:100
dim(x)<-c(10,10)
groups<-sample(c("red","blue"), 10, replace=TRUE)

x.clust<-as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(x)))

local({
  colLab <<- function(n) {
    if(is.leaf(n)) {
      a <- attributes(n)
      i <<- i+1
      attr(n, "edgePar") <-
        c(a$nodePar, list(col = mycols[i], lab.font= i%%3))
    }
    n
  }
  mycols <- groups
  i <- 0
})

x.clust.dend <- dendrapply(x.clust, colLab)
plot(x.clust.dend)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I am doing something wrong here but this doesn't work for me. I changed the `groups` variable to the column that I wanted an ran the exact same code replacing `x` with my own data frame. I get a usual dendrogram without colors.

Comment: Hi Pathebug, could you give a small example of your data frame? Note that in the above example that my groups variable is a character vector containing the colours "blue" and "red". In your case, your flag vector would thus also need to be a character vector of colours. If not, say your variable contains two groups, say apples and oranges, then you will need to create a new vector whereby apples and oranges refer to the colours you want.Flag<-sample(c("apples","oranges"), 10, replace=TRUE)
Flag.colours<-gsub("apples","red", Flag)
Flag.colours<-gsub("oranges","blue", Flag.colours)

Comment: You would then use Flag.colours to colour your branches. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have a similar question. However this code only works if you: 1) extract previously the order of the tips from the resulted cluster, 2) assign the tips to the categories and 3) assign a colour to each category. Is there any way to assign automatically the colours to the tips of the cluster based on a dataframe that contains the name of the tips IDs and its category or colour? As the `merge` function. In this way we don't have to extract the tips from the cluster. Thank you very much for this post!

Answer (score 2):

I think Arhopala's answer is good. I took the liberty to take a step further, and added the function `assign_values_to_leaves_edgePar` to the *[dendextend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TldIy.png)* package (starting from version 0.17.2, which is [now on github](https://github.com/talgalili/dendextend)). This version of the function is a bit more robust and flexible from Arhopala's answer since:

1. It is a general function which can work in different problems/settings
2. The function can deal with other edgePar parameters (col, lwd, lty)
3. The function offers recycling of partial vectors, and various warnings massages when needed.

To install the *[dendextend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TldIy.png)* package you can use `install.packages('dendextend')`, but for the latest version, use the following code:

```
require2 <- function (package, ...) {
    if (!require(package)) install.packages(package); library(package)
}

## require2('installr')
## install.Rtools() # run this if you are using Windows and don't have Rtools installed (you must have it for devtools)

# Load devtools:
require2("devtools")
devtools::install_github('talgalili/dendextend')
```

Now that we have dendextend installed, here is a second take on Arhopala's answer:

```
x<-1:100
dim(x)<-c(10,10)
set.seed(1)
groups<-sample(c("red","blue"), 10, replace=TRUE)
x.clust<-as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(x)))

x.clust.dend <- x.clust
x.clust.dend <- assign_values_to_leaves_edgePar(x.clust.dend, value = groups, edgePar = "col") # add the colors.
x.clust.dend <- assign_values_to_leaves_edgePar(x.clust.dend, value = 3, edgePar = "lwd") # make the lines thick
plot(x.clust.dend)
```

Here is the result:

[image]

p.s.: I personally prefer [using pipes](http://www.r-statistics.com/2014/08/simpler-r-coding-with-pipes-the-present-and-future-of-the-magrittr-package/) for this type of coding (which will give the same result as above, but is easier to read):

```
x.clust <- x %>% dist  %>% hclust %>% as.dendrogram
x.clust.dend <- x.clust %>% 
   assign_values_to_leaves_edgePar(value = groups, edgePar = "col") %>% # add the colors.
   assign_values_to_leaves_edgePar(value = 3, edgePar = "lwd") # make the lines thick
plot(x.clust.dend)
```