# Changing color of dendrogram branches Python

Tags: python, scipy, visualization, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I have succeeded in changing the color of leaf labels in my dendrogram according to its classification, but I want to follow this coloring upwards.

```
from scipy.cluster import hierarchy
import matplotlib as plt

#dist_matrix[i,j] is an upper triangle 2d array containing the euclidean distance between each row being compared

linkage_matrix = hierarchy.ward(dist_matrix)

#visualizing dendrogram with basic style elements
hierarchy.dendrogram(linkage_matrix, labels=df.index, leaf_rotation=0, orientation="left", color_threshold=5, above_threshold_color='grey',leaf_font_size=10)

#color codes rows according to column 'Location' in original dataframe
my_palette = plt.colormaps["Accent"]
df['Location']=pd.Categorical(df['Location'])
my_color=df['Location'].cat.codes
ax = plt.pyplot.gca()
xlbls = ax.get_ymajorticklabels()

#sets colors of x-labels according to above coding
num=0
for lbl in xlbls:
    val=my_color.iloc[num]
    lbl.set_color(my_palette(val))
    num+=1

plt.pyplot.figure(figsize=(10,15)) #plots resulting figure
```

The resulting figure looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9axs.png

I have tried reading through the SciPy documentation for the dendrogram, but haven't found a way to achieve this. The same problem was proposed, and recieved a solution, but in R instead of Python: [Color dendrogram branches based on external labels uptowards the root until the label matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36617699/color-dendrogram-branches-based-on-external-labels-uptowards-the-root-until-the?newreg=fbf58ac01d1f4b179c7d1168a08ed3d5)

Comment: there are many undefined variables. the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I tried to update it to include more variables, but I believe the crux of the issue is demonstrated

Comment: `df['Location']` does not exist because a dataframe has not been created.

Comment: `dist_matrix` does not exist, what is this ?

Comment: ...if users cannot reproduce the problem then how can they help you, unless the above 2 errors were the problem in the first case ?